# GraphQL "ID cannot represent value..." error, but mutation works fine

Tags: mongoose, graphql

I can't detect the problem.

I am using mongoose and the resolver works fine in DB,but i receive this error in GraphQL:

```
"errors": [
    {
      "message": "ID cannot represent value: <Buffer 5d d4 35 8d b1 d1 60 1e 38 34 7b fc>",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 8,
          "column": 7
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "deleteCollection",
        "products",
        0,
        "id"
      ]....
```

Here is my mutation resolver:

```
async deleteCollection(parent, args, context, info) {

    //find user
    const user = await context.User.findOne({ _id: args.id});

    //find collection
    const collection = await context.Collection.findOne({createdBy: args.id});

    //remove collection from user
    user.collections.pull(collection._id);

    //save user
    await user.save();

    //find products in collection
    const products = await context.Product.find({
      collections: { $in: [collection._id] }
    });

    //for every product in collection, remove it
    await products.map(
      async (product) => (
        product.collections.pull(collection._id), await product.save()
      )
    );

    //delete collection
    await context.Collection.deleteOne({
      _id: args.id
    });

    return collection;
  },
```

I am sure the problem is here :

```
//find products in collection
    const products = await context.Product.find({
      collections: { $in: [collection._id] }
    });

//for every product in collection, remove it
    await products.map(
      async (product) => (
        product.collections.pull(collection._id), await product.save()
      )
    );
```

because if no products are in collection, when i delete it , there is no error.
 Also I am using this resolver for  graphql`type Product`:

```
const Product = {
  id: (parent, args, context, info) => {
    return parent.id || parent._id;
  }
};
```

Please help